# Why is my UserControl's markup telling me "variable is not defined", despite variable being defined and public in code?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, user-controls, aspx-user-control

I have the following user control in my project:

Markup (`SlidingScaleTableReadonly.ascx`):

```xml
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="SlidingScaleTableReadonly.ascx.vb" Inherits="Client.Project.SlidingScaleTableReadonly" %>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Résultat glycémique</th>
            <th scope="col">Unité à administrer</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% For Each scaleEntry In ScaleEntries %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= scaleEntry.LowerValue %> - <%= scaleEntry.HigherValue %></td>
                <td><%= scaleEntry.UnitToDeliver %></td>
            </tr>
        <% Next %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Code (`SlidingScaleTableReadonly.ascx.vb`):

```vb
Public Class SlidingScaleTableReadonly
    Inherits UserControl

    Public ScaleEntries As List(Of ScaleEntry)

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

End Class
```

And the following error at line 11 in `SlidingScaleTableReadonly.ascx`:

> BC30451   'scaleEntries' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

I'd call the compiler wrong on this one; `scaleEntries` is defined and public. What's wrong then?

Comment: Even if it declared, based on the code we can see the value is still NULL.

Comment: Exit vs, then re-load. Now do a re-build all for the project - that should make those errors go away. Often sometimes they will STILL show, but if you build (or run) the project, they go away. I can't say when/why this occurs, but VS OFTEN will struggle to resolve those embedd server side expressions in the HTML markup.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn That would be a runtime problem (and it's addressed at runtime). Such errors don't show up in editing.

Comment: Actually, they often do! - you see compile errors in the error list. As per above, a rebuild all often makes the errors go away. But, I still think those server side expressions are incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exit vs, then re-load. Now do a re-build all for the project - that should make those errors go away. Often sometimes they will STILL show, but if you build (or run) the project, they go away. I can't say when/why this occurs, but VS OFTEN will struggle to resolve those imbedded  server side expressions in the HTML markup

In most cases a re-build all will fix this, but I have found that sometimes you have to exit VS, re-launch. Do a re-build all, and the error goes away.

Comment: Ah, yes - my sorry! - try the rebuild project - see if the error goes away. as noted, I often had to exit VS. re-launch. Open project, and then do a rebuild all. See if that works (I assume at one time it did???)

Comment: Yep, that's the solution. That's a frustrating bug, I hope VS will fix it eventually. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't know the when/why. But sometimes EVEN a re-build all does not fix. You have to exit VS and then re-enter, and THEN re-build all. But, usually JUST a re-build all will fix this.